how to make it work in yocto recipe cmake fetchcontent?
I am using fetchcontent on my project cmake file and i want to compile into my yocto project but its not working properly. I have written already on my recipe such things
EXTRA_OECMAKE:append = "-DFETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED=ON"
do_configure[network] =  "1"
do_compile[network] = "1"

but it didnt work.
I hope I explained situation clearly. Any help is appreciated.

https://zenn.dev/nbo/scraps/d485855bbf2d9b
here the solution
EXTRA_OECMAKE:append = "-DFETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED=OFF"

yocto is limiting the network connection(probably except gitsm command).
